# Formal definition of geometric transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Geometric transformation (2D) is function $\mathbf{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbf{R}^2$.

Let $O(0,0)$ and $P(x,y)$ are points on $\mathbf{R}^2$.

For 2D Translation:

$$(x, y) \rightarrow (x+a, y+b)$$

or matrix notation $\vec{OP} =  \left[ \begin{array}{c} x\\ y\\ \end{array} \right]$

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{c} x\\ y\\ \end{array} \right] \rightarrow \left[ \begin{array}{c} x\\ y\\ \end{array} \right] +\left[ \begin{array}{c} a\\ b\\ \end{array} \right] $$

A geometric transformation on the plane is a function or linear transformation?

Comment: Linear transformations are special, in that a linear transformation always maps the zero vector to the zero vector.  So, a translation is not a linear transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a general sense, a [transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_(function)) $T$ is a **function** that maps a set $X$ to itself, that is $T : X \to X$.

If $X$ is a vector space over a field $K$, we define:

**Definition (linear transformation).** Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$, we say that a transformation $T : V \to V$ is linear if and only if

1. $T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)$ for all $u,v \in V$.
2. $T(\alpha u) = \alpha T(u)$ for all $u \in V$ and for all $\alpha \in K$.

Therefore every linear transformation is a function, but not vice versa.

**Example 1.** Consider the vector space $R^2$ over the filed $R$, given a fixed point $(a,b) \in R^2$, we define the translation transformation $\mathbb{T}_{(a,b)}$ as

$$\begin{matrix} 
\mathbb{T}_{(a,b)} : & R^2 & \to & R^2\\
  & (x,y) & \mapsto & \mathbb{T}_{(a,b)}(x,y):= (x+a,y+b)\\
\end{matrix}
$$

Is $\mathbb{T}_{(a,b)}$ linear?, *no*, take $(a,b) = (x,y) = (z,w) = (1,1)$ and see if the condition $1.$ of linearity is fulfilled.

**Example 2.** Consider the vector space $M_{2 \times 1}(R)$ (the set of all real valued matrices with two rows and one column), over the filed $R$, given a fixed point $\begin{pmatrix} 
a\\
b
\end{pmatrix} \in M_{2 \times 1}(R)$, the translation transformation $\mathbb{T}_{\begin{pmatrix} 
a\\
b
\end{pmatrix} }$ is
$$\begin{matrix} 
\mathbb{T}_{\begin{pmatrix} 
a\\
b
\end{pmatrix} } : & M_{2 \times 1}(R) & \to & M_{2 \times 1}(R)\\
  &  \begin{pmatrix} 
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix} & \mapsto & \begin{pmatrix} 
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix} & \mathbb{T}_{\begin{pmatrix} 
a\\
b
\end{pmatrix}}\begin{pmatrix} 
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix} := \begin{pmatrix} 
x+a\\
y+b
\end{pmatrix}\\
\end{matrix}
$$

Is $\mathbb{T}_{(a,b)}$ linear?, *no*, again,  take $\begin{pmatrix} 
a\\
b
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
z\\
w
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$ and see if the condition $1.$ of linearity is fulfilled.